# Loop Dependence

Tags: c, parallel-processing

Say I have a nested loop as:

```
for(m=0;m<10;m++)
   for(n=0;n<10;n++)
      result[n][m]=result[m-3][n-2]
                   +result[n+1];
```

Would we call any of the two loops parallelizeable? My understanding is there is dependence on both the two variables n and m so we can't parallelize any of the loops.

Please clarify. Also, what type of dependences is this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's at `result[-3][-2]`?

Comment: You're missing an array index in the last subexpression `+result[n+1]`.

Comment: Anon: assume eliminating the negative indexes..

Comment: Adam: yes sorry that was  +result[n+1][m]

Comment: You know you can edit your answer to correct mistakes, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the example loop there is not parallelizeable (or at least not easily), but it's not because the inner contents rely on both `m` and `n` (as those could be passed as arguments to a new thread or whatever).  It's because later calculations depend on the results of earlier calculations.  For example, the value of `result[10][12]` depends on `result[9][8]` which depends on `result[5][7]` etc.